# Не могу вставить фоновое изображение на сайт, что делать?

Tags: html, css, изображения

```
@import url(reset.css);
#body {
    font: 13px/1.4 Arial, Verdana, Tahoma sans-serif;
    background: url(../images/main_bg.jpg);
}
```

Вставил картинку, обновляю страницу - фонового изображения нет, почему? Что я не так сделал?

Comment: `#body` ?? - это что вообще? вы уверены что не body{...}

Comment: Тут у меня 2 варианта - я думаю больше и быть не должно.
Вы либо ошибаетесь с `#body` либо вы ошиблись и ваш путь к файлу, относительно html файла не верен.

Answer (score 2):

```
  "#body" - как обращение к елементу с ID="body"

   Если хотите обратится к тагу <body></body> тогда в CSS надо 
   писать без решотки(#);
   body{
           font: 13px/1.4 Arial, Verdana, Tahoma sans-serif;
           background: url(../images/main_bg.jpg);
           }
```